# Use dropdown list selection as mySQL query parameter

Tags: php, javascript, jquery, mysql, ajax

I had asked a similar question a few days ago but think I was trying to do to much at one time.  I am hoping someone can help get me started on this.

I have two drop down lists, one will be populated with years (2012, 2011 etc) and I have some mySQL databases called "db_2012", "db_2011" etc.  In these databases are tables representing months.

I would like the user to select a year and then use that selection to query the correct db and return a list of table names which will be used to populate the second drop down list.  Then click a button "See Results" to query the selected table and show the results.

I am putting this on a wordpress website and am using a php template file that I created.  This is still new to me and what I have so far doesnt work like I want it too, it is basically setup now that you select a year and select a month (not populated from db) and click a button.  It makes the query and my table is displayed, but I need this solution to be more dynamic and work as described above.  Thanks for the help.

```
echo '<form action="" method="post">';
echo'<select name="years" id="years">';
foreach($yearList as $year){
    echo'<option value="'.$year.'">'.$year.'</option>';
}
echo'</select><br />';

echo '<select name="monthList" id="months">';
foreach($monthList as $month) {
    echo'<option value="'.$month.'">'.$month.'</option>';
}
echo '</select>';
echo '<input type=\'submit\' value=\'See Results\'>';
echo '</form'>
```

$yearList and $monthList are just pre populated arrays. So now from here I want to click the See Results button and query my sql database using the parameters from the drop down selections.

```
$database = $_POST['yearList'];
$month = $_POST['monthList'];

$wpdbtest_otherdb = new wpdb('Username', 'Password', $database, 'localhost');

$qStr = "SELECT * FROM $month";
$myResults = $wpdbtest_otherdb->get_results($qStr, OBJECT);
```

Comment: So.... what isn't working?  Cause this all seems fine...  You know, excepting the massive security concerns.

Comment: It doesn't work perk the requirement (I would like the user to select a year and then use that selection to query the correct db and return a list of table names which will be used to populate the second drop down list. Then click a button "See Results" to query the selected table and show the results.) - I will deal with security when I get the functionality working properly.

Comment: Clearly we're misunderstanding one another.  When I said "What isn't working? Cause this all seems fine...", I meant, "Please provide us with error messages, or pairs of expected vs. actual outputs, and the inputs you used to achieve those so that we, as a community, can diagnose the workflow of what you've written.  You've written code that is at least theoretically functional, and though we'd love to help you find your bug, we can't find it until we know what color it is."  Does that make more sense?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It sounds like you want to send an AJAX call to a separate php page for security and processing, then have the PHP return XML that you parse back into the second selection box via the AJAX callback.  It can be a little messy, but it allows you to check for weird form values that users might inject.

Edit: The PHP will receive your AJAX parameters as parts of the $_GET or the $_POST array.  From there, you can do your checks and db call (or not), then add `header("Content-Type:text/xml");` so the server sends it back with the correct header.  After that you'll need to echo the XML-formatted data you want the JavaScript to receive.  Just remember not to echo anything other than the XML if the request is supposed to go through.

Comment: Yep that sounds closer to what I am looking for, the problem is I have no idea how to do something like that in php.

Comment: Edited a bit to try and clarify.  This may also help:
http://www.satya-weblog.com/2008/02/header-for-xml-content-in-php-file.html